# How to change priority of make build process

Tags: c++, c, shell, makefile, nice

We have a Linux server with multiple users logged in. If someone runs `make -jN` it hogs the whole server CPU usage and responsiveness to other users decreases drastically.

Is there any way to decrease the `priority` of `make` process run by anyone in Linux?

Answer (score 3):

Make has a '-l' (--load-average) option.
If you specify 'make -l 3', make will not launch additional jobs if there are already jobs running and the load is over 3.

From the manpage:

> ```
>    -l [load], --load-average[=load]
>         Specifies that no new jobs (commands) should be started  if  there
>         are  others  jobs running and the load average is at least load (a
>         floating-point number).  With no argument, removes a previous load
>         limit.
> ```

It doesn't really decrease the priority of make, but it can avoid causing too much load.

Answer (score 1):

replace make with your own script and add a "nice -n <>" command, so that higher the -jN, more the niceness.

start a super-user process that does ps -u "user name" | grep make, and count the number of processes. use renice on the process ids make them in line, or any other algorithm you want

Comment: Not a clean solution, as multiple users are involved and make arguments are auto-generated from configure/automake tools

Comment: @Manav: that is not a problem.

Comment: The problem is that the original make will still need to be called, but people can then call it directly.

Comment: Now you have two answers in one. The problem with the second answer is that you'll be renicing make but not the processes that do the actual work.

Comment: you can renice all processes by the user, assuming build is the only thing they do using "renice -u "

Comment: @Nish: If you renice everything, the relative priorities do not change and nothing improves. The whole reason for `nice` is to change relative priorities by being selective.